# C# (Search button) that have a function of contains

Tags: c#, search, contains

> How to do searching even though it isn't exact but will show in the datagridview

[Datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbppe.png)

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaTdT.png)

```
            OleDbCommand cmdDatabase = new OleDbCommand("Select User_ID, Firstname, Lastname, Pass, Account_Type from Account where Lastname'"+textBox1.Text+"'", con);
            try
            {

                OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDatabase;
                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

                bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                sda.Update(dbdataset);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE in the SQL Statement, the % indicates any value before or after the text, so % before the text would accept "asdsad cavite" and the % after the text would accept "cavite dagma" - both together accept both ("asd CAVITE asd").

More to LIKE: [SQL LIKE Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
OleDbCommand cmdDatabase = new OleDbCommand("SELECT User_ID, Firstname, Lastname, Pass, Account_Type FROM Account WHERE Lastname LIKE %'"+textBox1.Text+"%'", con);
            try
            {

                OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                sda.SelectCommand = cmdDatabase;
                DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

                bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
                sda.Update(dbdataset);

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've got you right, but if you want a 'contains' like search you can use

```
OleDbCommand cmdDatabase = new OleDbCommand("Select User_ID, Firstname, Lastname, Pass, Account_Type from Account where Lastname LIKE '%"+textBox1.Text+"%'", con);
```

keyword is [Wildcards](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

your SQL-statement provides potential for sql-injection by the way

Comment: sorry for the codes, im confused on doing parameters

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
        using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
        conn.Open();
        using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()){
        DataTable table = null;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

table = new DataTable();
          cmd.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT SifraPacijenta, Ime, Prezime, DatumRodjenja, Adresa, Telefon FROM Pacijenti WHERE Ime + ' ' + Prezime LIKE '%{0}%' ORDER BY SifraPacijenta", tbPretragaImePrezime.Text);
           da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
           da.Fill(table);
}
}
            conn.Close();
            gridPacijenti.DataSource = table;
```